# Is there any evidence in the Qur'an or Hadith which permits delaying Adhan?

Tags: salat, ramadan

In our state in India, some of scholars in the mosques are trying to keep the accuracy of the Azan timing by calling the Azan 5 minutes earlier for Subh and 5 minutes later for Magrib. They are keeping some minutes delay for other Azan also. At the time of Ramadan, they will trying to keep more accuracy by delaying to start the  Azan up to 7 minutes. Is there any evidence in the Hadith to make the delay on the account of accuracy?

Comment: Well you should know that you can call for prayer at any time you want to offer a prayer no matter if you are a single person or a congregation. But the adhan of a mosque should never be before the time of a prayer unless it is known as we will find a hadith where the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) explains that ibn um Makthoum (May Allah be pleased with him) does adhan before fajr -so that people know they still have a bit time to eat (in ramadan) and prepare themselves for joining the prayer-  while Bilal (May Allah be pleased with him) calls for the prayer, but it can be "later"!

Answer (score -3):

Do  your research in Bukhari. It is Sunnah to start the fast as late as possible and finish it as the prescribed time not later than necessary. The prophet forbid going to extremes and making our Deen difficult. The sub- Continent in notorious for this.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer as we expect here (see [answer]) beside this seems to me lacking the necessary respect for other people and in opposition to our [be nice policy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)